# FOS UserBundle invitation: how to send an invite?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I installed the invitation extension to FOSUserBundle. Everything seems to be working fine but I can't understand how to send an invitation: do I have to implement it or it is already and I simply need to find the correct path (and what is it please?)

thanks

Comment: What extension did you install? What did you try yet?

Comment: No sorry, not an extension, I just followed these steps:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adding_invitation_registration.md

I'd need to understand how to send an invite. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `Invitation` object and persist it to the database. Also you need to send its information to your user.

In your controller you need to do something like this:

```
public function inviteAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $invitation = new Invitation();
    $em->persist($invitation);
    // and then just output your $invitation->getCode() to user
    // also don't forget to check invitation as sent: $invitation->send()
}
```

Comment: ok. Given that FOSUserBundle comes with login and registration forms ready I assumed the invitation form was ready as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing than you and I found out that it was all there on their GitHub repo, ready for me to use.

[FOSUserBundle Invitation Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adding_invitation_registration.rst)

You have to do it yourself, but all is well documented! Hope that helps.

Comment: all there? not really. not the part to send the invitation.